# Why does the output of my program keep changing? EAX register keeps changing value?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, masm

I wrote a program to find the length of the largest increasing sequence given a larger `array`(the `array` is initialized in c++ and the c++ main calls the procedure), I got the code compiled, however, the output of the program keeps changing?

I tried replacing and observing the registers, and they don't seem to have an effect on the program output at all.

Finally, I tried to delete all the instructions inside the procedure that would affect the `ret` (returns `EAX`), however, the program still output random integers on the console

```
Sequence.asm (.asm file)

.586
.MODEL flat,C


.data
.code




    longestSequence PROC USES  eax ebx esi edi ,theArrayOFFSET: PTR DWORD,theArraySize: DWORD
    LOCAL temp[10]: DWORD 
    LOCAL lengthc: DWORD
    LOCAL k: DWORD  
    LOCAL temp1: DWORD 
    LOCAL temp2: DWORD 



//the algorithm to find the longest sequence of integer should be here, but its not shown for simplicity and the program still output random integers

*
*
*
mov eax,8 //suppose I move 8 into eax, it still generates random output

ret
longestSequence ENDP


END
```

```
Class ConsoleApplication3(cpp file)

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int longestSequence(int array[], unsigned count);

int main()
{
    int array1[10] = { -5, 10, 20, 14, 17, 26, 42, 22, 19, -5 };
    int seq;


    seq = longestSequence(array1, 10);
    cout << seq << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output varies each time the program runs, for example:
1st run - `7338264`
2nd run - `19920684`

The correct output for `array1 =  { -5, 10, 20, 14, 17, 26, 42, 22, 19, -5 };` should be `4` because the length of the longest sequence is `4` for `{14,17,26,42}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PROC USES  eax` causes MASM to generate prologue code that saves `eax` on the stack when the function begins, and also epilogue code that restores its original value before each `ret`. This obliterates any value that you prepare in `eax` before exiting your function.

In other words, your

```
mov         eax,8  
ret
```

in actually translated into

```
mov         eax,8  
pop         edi  
pop         esi  
pop         ebx  
pop         eax  
leave  
ret
```

(In the calling code `eax` is probably used to temporarily store some address value. Address space randomization causes it to change from one session to another, which is what randomizes the value that you observe.)

Remove `eax` from `USES` list.

Comment: And this is why single-stepping the machine code, not the asm source, with your debugger, is a Good Idea when things get weird.  Especially when using tools that emit any extra asm instructions for you.